# Rewrite HTML as Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a script that loads an image based on parameters determined using javascript. The HTML is pasted below:

```
<div class="img-block" unselectable="on">
<div class="mh1" unselectable="on">
  <div class="caption" unselectable="on">
    <h2 unselectable="on">A - Z</h2>
  </div>
  <a href="default.aspx" unselectable="on">
    <img src="l102192015.jpg" alt="AtoZ" unselectable="on">
  </a></div></div>
```

The parameters for the src, href, and the header (A-Z) need to be determined via Javascript. Is there a way to re-write this block of code so that I can pass in these Javascript variables as parameters?

Thank you

Comment: yes there is. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily, especially using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), or with vanilla Javascript.

Let's assume you have an `<img>` like this:

```
<img src="" id="TestingImage" />
```

You can write a Javascript function to dynamically set any attribute based on strings:

**With jQuery**

```
function UpdateImage(){
    var src = "http://something.com/test.png";
    var title = "Testing Image";

    $("#TestingImage").attr("src", src);
    $("#TestingImage").attr("title", title);

    ... [etc]
}
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

```
function UpdateImage(){
    var src = "http://something.com/test.png";
    var title = "Testing Image";

    var image = document.getElementById("TestingImage");

    image.setAttribute("src", src);
    image.setAttribute("title", title);

    ... [etc]
}
```

All you have to do is set the attribute, and you can use any string/variable in your Javascript.